# Python Programming: how to eval values from dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, eval

Given string

```
str=" dept_id == CS1  and  student_count > 75 "
```

Dictionary

```
dict = {'dept_id': 'CS1' ,'student_count': 95 }
```

We need to substitute values from dict in string and evaluate

```
eval (str)
```

code below works for all integer cases :

```
for item in dict.items():
k , v  = item
if s.find(k) > -1:
 k=str(k)
 s=s.replace(k, str(v),1)
 print "replaced",s

print eval(s)
```

Is there any other way to approach this problem?

Comment: Using `eval()` is generally a bad idea. Why are you trying to do this. There is probably a better way.

Comment: I am using it to evaluate a variable expression whose values are available only during runtime.

Comment: Be careful with `eval()`, is that string provided by a user? If so, what do you think will happen if a user gives you this as input (I wouldn't recommend running it): `"__import__('subprocess').call('rm -r ~/')"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) accepts an optional dictionary (`globals`, `locals`). You don't need to replace the string manually:

```
>>> s = "dept_id == 'CS1' and student_count > 75 "
>>> d = {'dept_id': 'CS1' ,'student_count': 95 }
>>> eval(s, d)
True
>>> d = {'dept_id': 'CS1' ,'student_count': 35 }
>>> eval(s, d)
False
```

BTW, using `str`, `dict` as variable names is not a good idea. They will shadows builtin function/types [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dict).

Answer (score 3):

Anyway, found this useful while trying to find solution to my problem with dictionary provided as string:

```
import ast # helps with converting str representation of python data structures
dictionary = "{'a':'a1', 'b':'a2', 'c':'a3' }"
parsed_dictionary = ast.literal_eval(dictionary)
>>> {'a':'a1', 'b':'a2', 'c':'a3'}
```

It may not be the exact answer for the problem, but might be helpful for somebody looking for safe solution or having similar problem to mine.

Using `ast` library:

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

So as @IanAuld commented, I'd like to add that `ast.literal_eval()` is safer, because will raise an error while trying to parse string with structures other that listed above. Sure, `eval()` will delete data without hesitation ;) and I wouldn't recommend running this command.